# Adding a item into a a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that store the values as lists for each key. For example:

```
dict1={}
dict1["A"]=[]
```

I want to append numbers into this list now, but how do I do this correctly? I tried `dict1["A"]=dict1["A"].append(1)`

this only appended `"None"`. How do I do this?

Comment: This is probably because you are setting the value of appending the value to the key which returns `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to call `append()`

```
dict1["A"].append(1)
```

Since the return value of `append()` itself is None, your version just replaced the old value (a list) with `None` *after* you successfully added the item to the list.

A quick demo:

```
>>> dict1 = {'A': []}
>>> dict1['A'].append(1)
>>> dict1
{'A': [1]}
```

In Python, in-place operations such as appending to the list, return `None`:

```
>>> alist = []
>>> alist.append(1) is None
True
>>> alist
[1]
```

but as you can see, the list itself was changed.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reassign. Just do `dict1["A"].append(1)`.

The mistake you have done is `dict1["A"].append(1)` returns `None` and that you were assigning it back to `dict1`. Which explains the `None` you were getting...

Answer (score 1):

That's because `append()` changes the list in-place and returns `None`. In your code you assigned that returned Value to `dict1["A"]`

```
In [25]: dict1={}

In [26]: dict1["A"]=[]

In [27]: dict1["A"].append(1)  #try print dict1["A"].append(1) here

In [28]: dict1
Out[28]: {'A': [1]}
```